# Pasting hyperlinks with spaces into Skype for business

Tags: hyperlink, skype-for-business

My company uses Skype for Business (predominately on Windows 7 machines) as our primary internal instant messaging tool, and I have a problem pasting network share locations (files and folders) when the path contains 2 separate directories with a space.  For example, if I try to paste

```
\\server\share\folder\folder with space\another folder with space\folder\
```

Skype automatically tries to create a clickable link but auto-formats it to

```
<\\server\share\folder\folder with space\another> folder with space\folder\
```

which essentially breaks the link because it is now pointing too a directory that doesn't exist or the wrong directory.

Interestingly enough, it manages to handle the space in the higher level directory, but not the lower level one.  And if I paste with only 1 directory with a space, it works

```
\\server\share\folder\folder with space\folder\
```

is formatted correctly as a clickable link

```
<\\server\share\folder\folder with space\folder\>
```

I've tried pasted as unformatted text and preadding the `<` and `>` to create the hyperlink as pasted, wrapping link string in quotes, but nothing works since Skype autoformats the text as soon as it is pasted.

Other than removing the spaces from the directories (which often isn't possible since I don't own them), is there a reliable and simple way to paste links into Skype for Business and have it autoformat correctly?

Answer (score 5):

`<file:\\path\with spaces>` there shouldn't be double quotes. Then it works I have tested it with "Skype for Business 2016".

Comment: This is the answer!

Comment: ``\\path\with spaces\`` also works. The backslash at the end is needed, but the angle brackets are not. When the message is sent in Skype, it will add the angle brackets by itself.

Comment: "The backslash at the end is needed" worked for me

Comment: As I indicated, a single directory with spaces is fine.  but when you have multiple different directories with spaces, it doesn't work.  Although I don't think I tested on the 2016 version.

Answer (score 2):

To be clickable in Skype, a path must contain a **trailing backslash** when it contains spaces.

`\\some-folder\some path` will become `<\\some-folder\some>`

`\\some-folder\some path\` will become `<\\some-folder\some path\>`

Adding `file:` in front of the path will not change the above behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one 
`<file:"\\path\with spaces">`

Answer (score 1):

Use the hyperlink button (chain icon two to the left of the send button) and paste the link as the address, you can also change the text the link displays using this method.  Only fool proof method I've found, putting it between <> or "" didn't work for me, didn't try including the / at the end but that would only work for directories and not files anyway

Answer (score -1):

Surround the path in quotation marks: `"\\FileServer\My Folder"` and Skype will handle it correctly. You can even add the quotation marks after pasting it and it will still work.

Comment: I tried this method both before pasting and after, and it still formats the links incorrectly.

Comment: Your suggestion does not work.